# Google Maps API v3 Memory leaks

Tags: ajax, memory-leaks, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API v3 for my project and I can see that some serious memory leaks occur during browsing time.

I'm trying to find some kind of unload methods, for Gmap, but sadly with no results. I'm using ajax on my site, and every time I update info about markers I reload Map content. I tried doing it on Chrome and FF, same leaks on both browsers. Yesterday while working I somehow managed to reach 800MB ram for FF, that's when I noticed the problem.

Did anyone got any luck by solving this problem in v3?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://twitter.com/atlaz/status/50844794880131072

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing also severe memory leaks in V3.
I noticed they only occur in Internet Explorer (not in Chrome and not in Firefox (allthough they do use a lot of memory), thank you Microsoft), but there is little info about it on the internet.
When pressing F5 (refresh) the webpage gets reloaded and the memory is being released.
This is the only way I know of to release the memory in runtime.
Now I have to look into a way to restart from the point we pressed F5

Hope this helps.